# PayPal NVP API SetExpressCheckout ALLOWNOTE not working

Tags: paypal

Using PayPal NVP API 65.1. During SetExpressCheckout, I set ALLOWNOTE=1 however the PayPal payment page does not display an input field to enter a note. I've tried setting it to 'true' as well but PayPal complains about a data type error. So I know the field is being passed through to PayPal with a valid value. Still no dice. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried leaving it out altogether?  The default is to allow the note, so you shouldn't need to specify that at all unless you were wanting to disable it.  You might also want to try an updated API version.  They're up to 122.0 now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the required parameters.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

(Optional) Enables the buyer to enter a note to the merchant on the PayPal page during checkout. The note is returned in the GetExpressCheckoutDetails response and the DoExpressCheckoutPayment response. It is one of the following values:

0 – The buyer is unable to enter a note to the merchant.
1 – The buyer is able to enter a note to the merchant.
Character length and limitations: 1 single-byte numeric character

**ALLOWNOTE** This field is available since version 53.0.

Comment: Settings and parameters were set and the field was not showing. I checked and set the PayPal account settings and no change. A few months later, this simply started working as expected. No explanation.

Comment: That field has been deprecated as of Sept 2015. See here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/